# How to handle different UTF-8 normalizations with Apache Solr?

Tags: java, utf-8, solr

We’re getting data in different UTF-8 normalizations. We do get UTF-8 composed in most times, but also UTF-8 decomposed. We’d like to search over this data with Apache Solr and we’re running in some troubles now. I’ll give you an example (of [Rabbi Akiva Eger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiva_Eger)):

```
(1) NFD:    ʿAqîvâ Ben-Moše Êger    cabf417169cc827661cc822042656e2d4d6f73cc8c652045cc82676572
(2) NFC:    ʿAqîvâ Ben-Moše Êger    cabf4171c3ae76c3a22042656e2d4d6fc5a16520c38a676572
(3) ASCII:  Aqiva Ben-Mose Eger     41716976612042656e2d4d6f73652045676572
```

We found out that Solr doesn’t handle (1) equal to (2) or (3). This is a problem for us, because it’s only possible to type ASCII characters with a keyboard easily. When you search for (3) – typed with a keyboard – you won’t find the data of (1) or (2).

Is there an easy way to enable this via a Solr option or do we need to put out data in UTF-8 NFC, NFD and ASCII in our search index to get search results for all of the three variations!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [solr.ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory) which should solve the problem.

Comment: How will this filter solve the problem? We could filter for one form and if be decide to use NFD we still have the problem that no one will type UTF-8 decompose on a keyboard. I'm confused ...

Comment: Sorry, didn’t didn’t realize that the main problem is getting ASCII input. In that case, you’ll have to make sure the indexed data matches on an ASCII basis. For that, there’s `solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory` (on the Wiki page linked above, right below the `solr.ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory`) which should spit out ASCII. (I say “should”, because I haven’t the required extension installed and hence can’t try it.) For NFC, it should even be enough to use `solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` to get ASCII into the index. Of course this should also been done for the query, in case someone types in NFC.